# Strange display/rendering issue on Google Chrome that varies by device/OS

Tags: google-chrome, rendering, google-docs

They say a picture is worth 1,000 words. Let's hope so.

[image: What I see when I'm on Google Docs]
[image: What's being loaded, but doesn't display correctly]

To be clear, I am unable to see the drop shadow around the document, grayscale on the document ruler, and gray etchings/borders on the menu UI. Basically, everything is whitewashed. I am incredibly bamboozled.

These are the facts as they stand:

1. This problem occurs on my desktop (Ubuntu/Windows10), but not on my Macbook Pro (Catalina). All OS are using Chrome that I have signed into.
2. I have disabled all of my Chrome extensions and experienced the same issue.
3. I have used multiple monitors and experienced the same issue.
4. I have disabled my Chrome theme and experienced the same issue.
5. If I were to take a screenshot of just a select portion of the screen, the very act of that bounding box *reveals the missing grayscale and shadow!* However, when the screenshot is actually taken, everything is whitewashed. Similarly, if I click "Send Feedback" on Google Docs, a menu UI pops up, the rest of the web page is grayed out a bit, and all the missing grayscale and shadow suddenly becomes visible.
6. **This happens on other web pages.** The best example I can give is dndbeyond.com - I cannot see the little checkboxes for my spell slots because they are whitewashed and do not have the drop/box shadow.

[image: Where are my spell slots??]
[image: Found em -_-]

I hope I've presented the information correctly. I don't know much/anything about what's going on here and I certainly lack the vocabulary to be successful at Googling my answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I suspect it's your monitor. Check your calibration (e.g., gamma) from the monitor and from each OS. You can ask computer-related questions on [superuser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Wow, it was truly that embarassingly easy. I was using a "Neutral" preset color mode on all 3 of my monitors. Switching to sRGB made the shadows pop out. Thank you!! I don't think I can accept the comment as the correct answer though.